# Can suddenly only boot with "nomodeset" (radeon, 16.04)

Tags: boot, lubuntu, radeon, nomodeset

As of yesterday, I can only boot with the kernel option `nomodeset`. The only thing that happened before normal shutdown was an upgrade:

```
Start-Date: 2016-11-26  00:09:51
Commandline: apt-get -y dist-upgrade
Requested-By: XXXXX (1000)
Upgrade: imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2),     libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), python2.7:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), python3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), python3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpulse0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), libpulse0:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), tar:amd64 (1.28-2.1, 1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1)
End-Date: 2016-11-26  00:10:03
```

Lubuntu has been running for months now without problems. Now, if I try to boot normally, the screen just stays black. If I boot without `quiet` and `splash`, then I can see a lot of text rushing by (normal boot messages) and then the screen turns off and stays off. Normally, cryptsetup should ask me for my password at that point (my system partition is encrypted).

If I try to enter the password blindly, nothing happens (no HDD activity either). Interestingly, after some time, the green led on my DVD-Drive (???) starts flashing. There is nothing in there and I haven't used the drive in months.

```
:~$ sudo lshw -class display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fddc0000-fdddffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fdd00000-fdd1ffff
```

When booting with nomodeset, Lubuntu detects only one of my three screens and all menu icons and most text (including lxterminal text) are really small and unreadable. The "x" to close windows is only a single pixel in size.

If it matters: This system doesn't have UEFI and is not dual boot. I tried using an older kernel, with no success.

```
:~$ dmesg | grep 'drm'
[    1.789860] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.818735] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    1.818756] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[   11.759756] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[   11.759781] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

`modprobe radeon modeset=1` will turn the screen off and I am not able to do anything anymore until I hard-reset the computer.

I can't really find anything else on Google and I'm out of ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Facing exactly same problem. Just that the resolution is fine on my system but I am not able to play videos normally. Video playback is choppy but audio is fine.

Comment: After browsing through internet without any luck, I accessed my BIOS and set the settings to default. Now I can boot normally without having to add `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0`